Trying to pull time from a date/time field, but it's giving me a 5 digit number instead?
I'm trying to pull only the time from a column of date/time values. Essentially, I'm trying to track the submission times of certain files for my teammates, and I need the time values to create a report. I'm trying to use a simple =RIGHT(A2, x) formula, but it always returns a number, "67125" for the below data.
Additionally, it appears as "9/27/2022 16:06" but the field value is "9/27/2022  4:06:36 PM," which I'm guessing is part of the issue? I feel like I'm missing something very simple, but was hoping someone might be able to help me out.
I've tried "RIGHT" and I was going to try TEXTBEFORE/AFTER, but they don't seem to want to cooperate. I was hoping for an Excel formula, rather than digging into VBA, but I certainly can if that's my last resort.

Datetimes in Excel are formatted numbers.
